# How to Assert Multiple values from one single row in one line in Go

Tags: go

how to assert multiple values from single row one line

```
assert.Equal(t, expected_1, actual_1, expected_2, actual_2...)
```

my current code:

```
// act
row := tx.QueryRow("select operation, primary_key, before_change, change, changed_at from foo.bar = 'I' order by 1 desc limit 1;")

c := columns{}
row.Scan(&c.operation, &c.primaryKey, &c.beforeChange, &c.change, &c.changedAt)
assert.Equal(t, 0, c.primaryKey)
assert.Equal(t, "I", c.operation)
assert.Equal(t, "", c.beforeChange)
assert.Equal(t, "", c.change)
assert.NotEmpty(t, c.changedAt)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a library that does that; possibly by writing it yourself. But that's very unidiomatic, so I suggest not doing it.

Comment: Test assertions are one of those cases where being more verbose is actually _better_ than trying to be as concise and compact as possible.

Comment: Another option would be to do a deep-equal comparison on all of `c`, rather than on its individual fields. But as @Kaedys indicated, the more granular your test, the more useful it generally is.

Comment: good point thanks guys, I will keep note of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** You shouldn't do that.

Combining tests like that makes your code easier to write, but *less readable*.  More importantly, it makes a test failure harder to diagnose.  Suppose that 6 months from now, one of those tests starts failing. How will you know if the failure is due to `c.operation` not matching expectations, or `c.change`?

**Longer answer:** Consider doing a deep-equal comparison, with a textual diff output.

By combining `reflect.DeepEqual`, [go-spew](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew), and a diff library, you can easily put together an assertion method that does a deep equal comparison of two structs, and if they don't match, produces a textual diff output that will make it easy to diagnose a failure.

I have a library that does this for use in my own personal projects. [github.com/flimzy/diff](http://godoc.org/github.com/flimzy/diff) It's not really intended for public consumption--I suggest just using it only for inspiration. But using it as an example:

```
row := tx.QueryRow("select operation, primary_key, before_change, change, changed_at from foo.bar = 'I' order by 1 desc limit 1;")

c := columns{}
row.Scan(&c.operation, &c.primaryKey, &c.beforeChange, &c.change, &c.changedAt)
expected := columns{
    operation: "I",
}
if d := diff.Interface(expected, c); d != "" {
    t.Error(d)
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for the reader how to handle the `changedAt` column in such tests.